# Detect audio pattern

Tags: audio, statistics, wav

I could use some help on audio analysis. What I'm trying to do is find specific patterns in audio files. The thing is is that I don't have an exact audio reference, I'm just trying to find similar patterns in the file.
So far I've computed the RMS over the track, as we can see it's quite easy to see the difference between the sound and the ones I want to extract (the ones pointed by the arrows).

[image]

I've tried computing standard deviation but nothing interesting came out of it.
So I'm open to all suggestion, to any statistics property that I should look into.

```
   float rms(short* buffer, int length){
        float avg = 0;
        float sum = 0;
        for (int i=0;i < length;++i){
            sum += buffer[i];
        }
        avg = sum / (float)length;
        float summean = 0;
        for (int i = 0;i < length;++i){
            summean += (buffer[i] - avg) * (buffer[i] - avg);
        }
        return pow(summean / (float)length, 0.5);
    }

        void main(){
            SndfileHandle file = read_file("audio_file.wav");
            float* avgBuffer; //the buffer is allocated somewhere else     
            float seconds = 0.03;
            int bufferLength = seconds * 16000; //samplerate

            short* buffer = (short*)malloc(sizeof(short) * bufferLength);

            while ((len = file.read(buffer, bufferLength))){
                avgBuffer[x] = rms(buffer, len);
                x++;
            }
            display(avgBuffer); //displays the red graph

    }
```

Comment: As it stands, this question is rather [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow - please [edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29388356/edit) and narrow it down to a more-specific coding problem. Also, it would be helpful if you would [post your code here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can see exactly what you're doing. **EDIT:** Alternatively, you could try asking on [one of the other Stack Exchange sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites) (such as the [Signal Processing](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) one).

Comment: I will have a look at the other Stack Exchange sites, thanks for the help.